# Font Awesome 5 not spinning icon?

Tags: font-awesome

I have an MVC project with Bootsrap 4 (SASS) and Font Awesome 5. I'm trying to get an spinning icon to work for use with an Ajax loading panel but it's not working.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Test Spin
</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> Test icon
</a>
```

I have the following buttons for testing. The one with just the icon in the button displays the FA icon but the button with the FAS spinning icon doesn't display.

For FontAwesome all I have is the `"~/Scripts/fontawesome-all.min.js"` file referenced. From my understanding that's all I needed to do?

This is my bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vendorscripts").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/fontawesome-all.min.js"));
```

This is my layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vendorscripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `fa-spin` class also to make it spin.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Test Spin
</a>
```

Comment: He uses `fa-pulse` which is similar to `fa-spin`.

Comment: I had used `fas fa-spinner fa-spin-pulse` which didn't work. This should be marked as the answer.